# Neo4j Embedded with java

Tags: neo4j

I want to write a parametrized Query in Neo4j.
For this Im writing the source code in java. But Im not getting the correct way to query it Neo4j. Can anyone tell me the entire procedure of how to give the target of Neo4j in Java and how to query it in Neo4j.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the code, of your attempts. Also you can parametrize cypher also to the server, using the transactional http endpoint (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html) . Or the Neo4j-JDBC driver http://www.neo4j.org/develop/tools/jdbc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of great examples in the Neo4j Documentation.

For Cypher queries from Java you can use the ExecutionEngine documented here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html